# Automatically Parse JSON to RealmSwift (after Realm update) (UPDATED!)

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing, realm

I have an application developed with Swift that uses an automatic system of parsing from a JSON to a Realm database.

Until Realm version 10.7.2, the following code worked correctly:

```
      case .string:
    if property.isArray {
      if let list = object[property.name] as? RealmSwift.ListBase, let arrayInfo = subInfo.array {
        for str in arrayInfo {
          list._rlmArray.add(str.string! as AnyObject)
        }
      }
    } else {
      object[property.name] = subInfo.getString()
    }
```

When updating to the latest version I get a series of errors that I have managed to correct in part, but not all.

For example, RealmSwift.ListBase has changed to RLMSwiftCollectionBase:
[image]

Error: *No type named 'ListBase' in module 'RealmSwift'*

And _rlmArray has changed to _rlmCollection:
[image]

Error: *Value of type 'RLMSwiftCollectionBase' has no member '_rlmArray'*

But now I can't add the text strings to this collection.
[image]

Error: *Value of type 'RLMCollection' has no member 'add'*

Some help about how to update de JSON parsing to RealmSwift database?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not be using RealmSwift.Listbase at all because it's not a publicly facing function. From the docs *nodoc: Internal Class: Do not use directly*. So there's a high chance that something under the hood changed which broke your code. Also, _rlmCollection is another non-public function which has changed. In general it’s a good idea to include errors as *text*; images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Updated with error texts to make it searchable. So, there is no way to make such a 'automatic parsing' as previously on Release 10.7.2?

Comment: The code is a bit unclear without context so I am not sure what's being asked. The code references a number of vars but without knowing what those vars represent it would be hard to understand what's going on. For example `object[property.name]` looks like an array but what is `property.name`? We have no idea what `arrayInfo = subInfo.array` subinfo.array is. If arrayInfo is an array of strings you can add them to the List with one statement instead of iterating `myRealmList.append(objectsIn: stringArray)`. But I don't know if that's the intention.